# 'linker command failed', 'GenerateDSYMFile errors', and 'Lipo error'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, git

I changed my project name recently and believe I may be having linking problems. I modified my Cocoapod files for Mixpanel yesterday and have been getting unclear error messages since.

I deleted the Mixpanel Cocoapod, so I could manually install Mixpanel with the git repository. I installed the git repo files in iOS project directory, but couldn't get Mixpanel working. I decided to revert back to using the Cocoapod.

Ever since I made that change, I have been getting 'linker command failed', 'GenerateDSYMFile errors', and 'Lipo error'. I have reverted my entire git repo back to before the problem existed, but I can't seem to shake the errors.

I deleted the derived data, snapshots, and restarted xcode. I have even tried to run the same repository of files on another computer. I am still having the issues.

For the curious, the repository is here: https://github.com/NewPublicArtFoundation/GraffitiFound

The current error I find is:

```
Ld /Users/lbogdono/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraffitiFound-axmdvgkvpehlnwgtxecternwbifq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Public\ Art.temp_caseinsensitive_renameTests.xctest/Public\ Art.temp_caseinsensitive_renameTests normal x86_64
    cd /Users/lbogdono/Spaceship/GraffitiFound
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.12
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/lbogdono/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraffitiFound-axmdvgkvpehlnwgtxecternwbifq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/lbogdono/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraffitiFound-axmdvgkvpehlnwgtxecternwbifq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/lbogdono/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraffitiFound-axmdvgkvpehlnwgtxecternwbifq/Build/Intermediates/Public\ Art.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Public\ Art.Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Public\ Art.temp_caseinsensitive_renameTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -bundle_loader /Users/lbogdono/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraffitiFound-axmdvgkvpehlnwgtxecternwbifq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GraffitiFound.app/GraffitiFound -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.12 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/lbogdono/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraffitiFound-axmdvgkvpehlnwgtxecternwbifq/Build/Intermediates/Public\ Art.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Public\ Art.Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Public\ Art.temp_caseinsensitive_renameTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/lbogdono/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraffitiFound-axmdvgkvpehlnwgtxecternwbifq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Public\ Art.temp_caseinsensitive_renameTests.xctest/Public\ Art.temp_caseinsensitive_renameTests

ld: file not found: /Users/lbogdono/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraffitiFound-axmdvgkvpehlnwgtxecternwbifq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GraffitiFound.app/GraffitiFound
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you are trying to link a file into your executable that is not present on disk.  Specifically, it is unable to find `/Users/lbogdono/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraffitiFound-axmdvgkvpehlnwgtxecternwbifq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GraffitiFound.app/GraffitiFound`  I suspect you are trying to link that into the executable on accident as it doesn't really make sense for it to be there.  You probably accidentally dragged "GraffitiFound.app" into the link phase of your target.